# How to overlay image in HTML over text in CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to overlay two images in HTML code over text that is displayed on my webpage in CSS, what is the simplest way to accomplish this. I want these two images on top of the text that is currently on top of these images.

HTML Code:

```
<body>
            <img src="" id="image" style="width:270px;height:270px; position:absolute; left:2270px;top:770px;"/>
            <img src="" id="image1" style="width:270px;height:270px; position:absolute; left:30px;top:770px;"/>
    </body>
```

Comment: Can u share a link to codepen or something?

Comment: Are you trying to put the images on top of each other? Or do you have text that you what them on top of (or behind)?

Comment: @jack Yes, I have text that I want them on top of, but currently the text is over the image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `z-index`, `position: relative;` and `position: absolute;`.
Here is your HTML:

```
<body>
   <img src="" id="image" style="width:270px;height:270px;"/>
   <img src="" id="image1" style="width:270px;height:270px;"/>
   This is a text!
</body>
```

Then add CSS:

```
img {
   position: relative;
   z-index: 1;
}

div {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px; //To see the difference
}
```

CodePen: https://codepen.io/marchmello/pen/ExjqGYQ

Comment: Awesome! Thank you @MARSHMALLOW This worked perfect

Answer (score 2):

You should use `z-index` for overlaying text and images:

```css
img {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  width: 200px;
}

div {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg" />
<div>This is text over the image that goes on for a while</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped alot